# My grandfathers patent, expired?

Tags: ownership, expiration, expired-patent, us948162

In reference to the patent: [US 948,162 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US948162)

I'm wondering if this patent has expired, and the process to claim it? This is my great-grandfathers invention.

Answer (score 2):

This patent has been expired since 1927, and since then it has been freely available for anyone to manufacture and sell.

If by "claim", you mean a [patent model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_model) (miniature model of the invention), those were only required until 1880, so there is no actual physical device stored anywhere, just the paperwork (if the originals still exist). The [scanned PDF](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US948162.pdf) on Google Patents is the closest you'll get to the original documentation, unless your grandfather retained a copy.